# Apache Karaf creating component twice

Tags: java, apache-karaf

Got a problem with **Apache Karaf 4.2.7**, trying to install features from my main component using FeatureService.

After installing feature all my components activating twice.

Does anybody know what's the problem?

I have the gradle module with bnd plugin

```
tasks.jar {
    withConvention(aQute.bnd.gradle.BundleTaskConvention::class) {
        bnd("""Export-Package: !*
               Import-Package: \
                    sun.jvmstat.*;resolution:=optional,\
                    com.sun.tools.attach;resolution:=optional,\
                    ru.sbrf.utracer.sensor.api.*;resolution:=optional,\
                    ru.sbrf.utracer.init.*;resolution:=optional,\
                    io.netty.*;resolution:=optional,\
                    *
            """.trimIndent())
    }
}
```

```
@Component(immediate = true)
public class Server implements MetricSender {

    private String host;
    private String port;
    private HttpClient httpClient;

    @Activate
    public void activate(Map<String, String> properties) {
        System.out.println("[SERVER] activate");
        connect();
    }

    private void connect() {
        httpClient = new NettyHttp2Client(host, Integer.parseInt(port));
    }
```

Duplicated only when NettyHttp2Client invoke `bootstrap.connect().sync();` inside.

Comment: Any logs? Information about Karaf version used? Your feature definition you've used? All these would help if you want to get an informative answer.

Comment: Added to report above. So if I remove line with httpClient initialization, activate method invoked once, otherwise invoked twice

Answer (score 0):

I suspect your component's bundle may be getting re-wired with some of those optional package imports you have specified. During boot-up, your component is probably being activated, then shutdown and re-activated when the additional optional packages become available.